Edge driver older version required
I need edge driver with version 86.0.622.38
Not able to find this edge driver version 86.0.622.38 on the official site. Also, tried searching on different sites.
Not able to find this edge driver version 86.0.622.38 on the official site. Also, tried searching on different sites.
https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/86.0.622.38/edgedriver_win64.zip
